# Android Studio inital gradle build takes a long time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've been using android studio for a few weeks now and noticed that it's been getting slower when restarted every time. The actual problem is that it seems to be stuck with the initial "Gradle Build Running" and started taking a few minutes to complete but now takes about 30+ minutes before it lets me actually use it. When this initial build is done it builds/cleans the project in about 4-7 seconds so it's only a recurring issue when I restart it.

One thing it could be is that the internet is awful (has a ping of about 500 ms), could that be related?

Hope someone can help!

**Edit**: Tried gradle offline mode, no luck there. After a further restart it even takes a long to stop the build too, it's been trying to stop the gradle build for about 10 minutes now...

Comment: Use offline gradle.open settings and search gradle

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be related to your slow internet connection. Gradle re-downloads its dependencies at first run. It will be faster if you enable offline mode. To enable offline mode, Go to Preferences > Gradle and check "Offline work".

If you need to download any new dependency, disable offline work and sync project and disable it again.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work, exact same issue. I did learn that it's not just the build command but if it tries to stop the build command too!